# Oracle SQL string date convert

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

I need to format/convert a dummy date with Oracle SQL, but I'm getting the following error message:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

The SQL command:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('January 3, 2011', 'DD-MM-YY') FROM dual;
```

Comment: And [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) is a link to the docs

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear.  If you actually have a date that you want to convert to a string, you would use the `to_char` function

```
SELECT to_char( date '2011-01-03', 'DD-MM-YY' )
  FROM dual
```

In the code you posted, however, it appears that you have a string that represents a date and you want to convert that to a different string that represents the same date in a different format.  If that is the case, you'd need to convert the string to a date and then convert the date back to a string

```
SELECT to_char( to_date( 'January 3, 2011', 'Month DD, YYYY' ),
                'DD-MM-YY' )
  FROM dual
```